# Why does my if statement fail when run within a crontab on Ubuntu (12.04 and 14.04)?

Tags: bash, cron

I have written a small bash script to archive my .bash_history file, to allow me to keep the regular .bash_history file reasonably small, but keep the history in a .bash_history.archive file forever.  When I run it from the command line, it works just fine, but when it runs from a crontab (on Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04), it fails with an error message like this:

`/usr/local/bin/archive_bash_history: 7: 
 /usr/local/bin/archive_bash_history: 15222: not found`

The script is:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 umask 077
 max_lines=50000

 linecount=$(wc -l < ~/.bash_history)

 if (($linecount > $max_lines)); then
         prune_lines=$(($linecount - $max_lines))
         head -$prune_lines ~/.bash_history >> ~/.bash_history.archive \
                && sed -e "1,${prune_lines}d"  ~/.bash_history > ~/.bash_history.tmp$$ \
                && mv ~/.bash_history.tmp$$ ~/.bash_history
 fi
```

the 15222 number is the number of lines in the .bash_history file when it runs.

Comment: Aside: Put `SHELL=/bin/bash` at the top of your crontab, and you probably wouldn't see this.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: The `#!/bin/bash` is enough to ensure that the script is executed by bash, assuming it's invoked properly.

Comment: @KeithThompson, certainly so; I at no point intended to state or imply anything to the contrary. (Indeed, see my comment on Kern's answer affirming Gordon's chain of reasoning).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Ok. But why would adding `SHELL=/bin/bash` to the crontab change the behavior? The problem turned out to be a space in front of the `#!`, which means that the script will be executed by `/bin/sh` regardless of the value of `$SHELL`.

Comment: @KeithThompson, "the script will be executed by `/bin/sh` regardless of the value of `$SHELL`" isn't accurate; bash will execute scripts without a valid shebang with itself. That's why the OP was asking why they couldn't reproduce the problem from their command line.

Comment: @KeithThompson, ...so, setting `SHELL` tells cron itself to use bash rather than /bin/sh, hence we get bash's default use-theyself behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: see ie. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94456/how-to-change-cron-shell-sh-to-bash

Comment: To be sure, it's an ugly hack, as opposed to the Right Thing of actually fixing the shebang. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Hmm, you're right.  I didn't know about that feature of bash (and I think I dislike it). Of course the right solution is to use a proper `#!`, but I stand^H^H^H^H^H sit corrected.

Answer (score 4):

It could be because your script is running in a plain POSIX shell rather than bash. `(( ))` is a bash extension, and if you run that `if (( ... )); then` line in a shell that doesn't have it, it'll create a subshell of a subshell to run the command `$linecount > $max_lines` -- which means it tries to execute `15222` as a command, with output redirected into a file named "50000". Not what you wanted at all.

As for why this happened... my guess is that it's because you had a space before the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`). In order for a shebang to be recognized by the OS, the "#!" *must* be the first two bytes of the file. Since that wasn't recognized, cron probably fell back to running it with /bin/sh. When you run it from the command line, you're using bash, and its fallback is to use itself.

Answer (score 0):

So as I was typing this up, I decided to try modifying the line to be quoted -- and noticed that each of the lines in my script had a space at the beginning of the line.  I'm not entirely sure why it works if I run it from a bash shell, but doesn't when I run it from the crontab, but removing the leading space on each line fixed the problem.

Any suggestions about why this might be the case, I'd be interested in knowing.

Comment: On the command line initial spaces suppress history.  I would be surprised if they broke a script.

Comment: @chicks, rather, it would be a broken shebang here changing the active interpreter. No effect from any line here but the first.